# map of list in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

How do I iterate over a map of list using aura:iteration.
I'm returning `Map<object,List<string>>`from apex, but not sure how do I pass it to the component.
To Be more clear I'm trying to get the accounts by created date.
If I use

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.accountlist}" var="acc">
       {!acc.createddate}
       <hr/>
       {!acc.Name}
    </aura:iteration>
```

the created date will be printed once for each record, if there are multiple accounts created on the sameday. Instead I want to display the all the records based on the createddate.

Apex:

```
return [SELECT createddate,name FROM Account]
```

I modified the query to return `Map<createdDate, List<Account>>`

Comment: Could you share a working example having the issue?

Comment: I don't have a working example, I'm returning a map of list from apex but not sure how do I manipulate it in the controller. I have updated my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below: This code is with the assumption you have multiple keys for different date with list of accounts for each date

```
var accountmap = component.get('v.accountList');
var accountList = [];

for ( var key in accountmap ) {
     accountList.push({accountdate:key, value:accountmap[key]});
     }
```

set accountList to an attribute in your component.

In your markup

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.accountlist}" var="acc">
       {!acc.accountdate}
      <aura:iteration items="{!acc.value}" var="account">
       <p>{!account}</p>
      </aura:iteration>

    </aura:iteration>
```

Comment: tried..its working perfectly :)

Comment: I was just trying this, component.get('v.accountList'); is always going to be null and it doesn't enter the for loop, or am I missing something?

Comment: if accountlist is coming from a init call on the component. inside callback get that value and then run the loop. first time on init  the accountList will be null. you will only be setting it inside callback

Answer (score -3):

for this you have to send  a `SET<key> and Map<key,list<string>>` from apex controller. in controller js you have set the values into to attribute.

and do nested iteraton.

```
<aura:iteration item="map" var="obj">
<aura:iteration item="set" var="obj1">
  {!obj.obj1} // here you getting the list 
</aur:iteration>
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: Your answer is not clear nor aligned to what OP is asking.

Comment: let me know where you getting block